# modify file in java

Tags: java, file, properties

I am trying to modify the value corresponding to `ip` in the file settings. In the console it prints me the desired result after I call `changeIp()` but it doesn't change the file

This is what I have done:

```
public class Settings {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        changeIp("abc");
    }
    public static void changeIp(String ip) {
        Properties ps = new Properties();
        // Create the file object
        File fileObj = new File("settings.txt");
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileObj);
            ps.load(fis);
            ps.put("ip", ip);
            System.out.println("Get A:" + ps.getProperty("ip"));

        } catch (Exception err) {
            err.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I have to mention that the file already exists and it has some preset values

Comment: Why do you think your code should change the file? Which part exactly should ensure that your file should be changed?

Comment: You never save the file after changing the property.

Comment: you've read the file but never wrote anything

Comment: Doesn't ps.put("ip",ip) change the value?

Comment: No it doesn't (change the file [this is what you're asking about]) and the JavaDoc doesn't says that. It just changes a value pf `ps` and nothing else.

Comment: in the Properties object but not in the file

Comment: Yes. But there's nothing that write the contents of ps to a file.

Comment: FileOutputStream or as stated in the answer use store()

Comment: You forget to close your file descriptor... What is more, `.printStackTrace()` is not the way to handle exceptions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use [Properties.store()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#store%28java.io.Writer,%20java.lang.String%29) to write the properties to a file.

```
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("output-file-name.properties");
ps.store(os, "");
```

Comment: how do I use it? there are 2 ways, with the parameters OutputStream, String or Writer, String?

Answer (score 1):

`ps.put("ip",ip)` updates value of `Properties` object located on heap, not value in file from hard drive.

If you want to wire state of Properties object to file you need to do it explicitly.

So just like `ps.load(fis)` is responsible for loading state from source to `Properties` object, `ps.store(output,comment)` can be used to store state of Properties in desired output stream which could point to file.

Comment: it gives me an error when I write: ps.store(fis). It tells me to rename store

Comment: My answer wasn't about `fis` but `fos` which would refer to `FileOutputStream`.